# Variance Components Analysis

Tags: variance, random-effects-model, sas

I have lab data, which is part of an R&R analysis. The data includes one numerical variable (let's call it Y), and a few factors (like site, day of running, lot,...), I will call them X1 X2 X3 and X4. And, for every combination of the factors, I have duplicates (two readings). I wish to perform a variance analysis, which means to calculate the total variance, and the % of variance related to any factor. I am going to do this using SAS, with PROC MIXED or PROC VARCOMP. So far so good. My two questions are: 1. I was asked to calculate for every factor, the between factor variability, e.g., between lot variability, between day variability and so forth, this is obtained easy from the PROC's I mentioned. But, I was also asked to add the CV (coefficient of variation). I need to device the SD by the mean, but which mean should I use ? The total mean ? If I want the CV for the lots, which mean should I take ? 2. How do I treat the duplicated ? Should I enter another variable to the model to represent the duplicates, or their variability will be obtained in the residual of the model?

Comment: what's R&R analysis?

Comment: repeatability and reproducibility. However, it does not matter much. Assume that I run PROC MIXED with no fixed effects and only random effects, not including the duplicates because I wonder if they will be reflected in the residual. SAS will give me the variances I need automatically, but how shall I calculate CV's ? Using which mean exactly?

Comment: As part of the output available from SAS Proc Mixed, you should be able to generate *adjusted* metrics such as the variance (as you note) as well as the mean for each level in the model. In my opinion, these adjusted metrics would form the basis of your estimates for the CVs, not the *observed* values.